# How to colorize single line of source code after clicking it using html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

Having colorized source code (by GeSHi or tool like http://tohtml.com) like this:

```
<pre style='color:#000000;background:#ffffff;'>
<ol>
<li><a href="#1"><span style='color:#004a43; '>#</span><span style='color:#004a43; '>include </span><span style='color:#800000; '>&lt;</span><span style='color:#40015a; '>iostream</span><span style='color:#800000; '>></span></a></li>
<li> </li>
<li><span style='color:#800000; font-weight:bold; '>using</span> <span style='color:#800000; font-weight:bold; '>namespace</span> <span style='color:#666616; '>std</span><span style='color:#800080; '>;</span></li></li>
<li> </li>
<li><span style='color:#800000; font-weight:bold; '>int</span> <span style='color:#400000; '>main</span><span style='color:#808030; '>(</span><span style='color:#808030; '>)</span> <span style='color:#800080; '>{</span></li>
<li> </li>
<li>    <span style='color:#800000; font-weight:bold; '>int</span> intNum <span style='color:#808030; '>=</span> <span style='color:#008c00; '>0</span><span style='color:#800080; '>;</span></li>
<li>    </li>
<li>    <span style='color:#603000; '>cin</span> <span style='color:#808030; '>></span><span style='color:#808030; '>></span> intNum<span style='color:#800080; '>;</span></li>
<li>    <span style='color:#800000; font-weight:bold; '>while</span> <span style='color:#808030; '>(</span>intNum <span style='color:#808030; '>!</span><span style='color:#808030; '>=</span> <span style='color:#008c00; '>42</span><span style='color:#808030; '>)</span> <span style='color:#800080; '>{</span></li>
<li>        <span style='color:#603000; '>cout</span> <span style='color:#808030; '>&lt;</span><span style='color:#808030; '>&lt;</span> intNum <span style='color:#808030; '>&lt;</span><span style='color:#808030; '>&lt;</span> <span style='color:#800000; '>"</span><span style='color:#0f69ff; '>\n</span><span style='color:#800000; '>"</span><span style='color:#800080; '>;</span></li>
<li>        <span style='color:#603000; '>cin</span> <span style='color:#808030; '>></span><span style='color:#808030; '>></span> intNum<span style='color:#800080; '>;</span></li>
<li>    <span style='color:#800080; '>}</span></li>
<li> </li>
<li>    <span style='color:#800000; font-weight:bold; '>return</span> <span style='color:#008c00; '>0</span><span style='color:#800080; '>;</span></li>
<li> </li>
<li><span style='color:#800080; '>}</span></li>
</ol>
</pre>
```

screenshot:

[image]

I want to create mechanism which will colorize clicked by user line. I know that I need to change background-color of specific li element. I wondering how can I achieve that.

Is this will be ok, to add to each line:

`<li`**`id='id1'`**`>`**`<a href="javascript:color('1')">...</a>`**`</li>`

`<li`**`id='id2'`**`>`**`<a href="javascript:color('2')">...</a>`**`</li>`

- Is it necessary, to add unique id to each li element?
- Is it possible to pass to JS function some kind of id/"this pointer"/whatever what will point JS function, which element should be changed?

**EDIT:**

One more requirement: after all, I need to pass information about which line was clicked, to URL. I want to do that without reloading a webpage, so I want to add something like #NUMBER_OF_CLICKED_LINE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to simply highlight the list elements is to use:

```
var ol = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0];
var lis = ol.getElementsByTagName('li');
var highlight = '#ffa';

for (i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
    lis[i].onclick = function(){
        this.style.backgroundColor = highlight;
    };  
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XMLxr/).

With regards to the need for the clicked-line to be appended to the URL as a hash (something which can't be easily demonstrated by JS Fiddle):

```
var ol = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0];
var lis = ol.getElementsByTagName('li');
var highlight = '#ffa';

for (i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
        lis[i].setAttribute('data-Index',i);
    lis[i].onclick = function(){
        this.style.backgroundColor = highlight;
        document.location.hash = 'line=' + this.getAttribute('data-index');
    };  
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XMLxr/2/).

Comment: unfortunately `this.setAttribute('data-Index',i);` will be called for each line, and it will end with a number of last line.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the case, in Chromium 14/Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a jQuery tag, but if it's an option to use Jquery you can simply bind a click event to `<li>` like so:

```
$('li').click(function () {
   $(this).css('background', '#somecolor'); 
   /* This will only alter the clicked li element */
});
```

**Edit:**

For your line-number-in-hash requirement you could add the attribute `data-linenumber={thelinenumber}` to your li elements. ( I'd avoid using `id` for this as it might conflict with other css/javascript already in place. )

Then change it to:

```
$('li').click(function () {
   $(this).css('background', '#somecolor'); 
   window.location.hash = 'linenumber' + $(this).attr('data-linenumber');
   /* this assumes that your hash is currently empty and/or replaceable. */
});
```

Comment: good solution, but for some reason I also need to add #line=NUMBER to url. Is it possible to do that without A element?

Comment: Can you edit your question to better explain your requirement?

Comment: `<li data-linenumber="1">`... will be ugly :/

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly you want the linenumber in hash, but I suppose you could calculate the linenumber in the click event handler rather than looking it up, so you wont find it 'ugly'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/ will help you.

it automatically: finds blocks of code, detects a language, highlights it.

The library knows 41 languages and has 16 style themes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function color(element) {
        element.style.color="red";
    }
</script> 

<body>
    This is test <span onclick="color(this);">Make it color</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put `id`s on each line, though you can. You probably do want to put an `id` on the `ol`. You'll then write some javascript placed after this code (preferably using jQuery, but not necessarily) that get's the `ol` element by id, iterates though it's children, and for each child that is an `li` attaches an click handler. If you're not using a library like jQuery, look at some flexible [click handler code](http://ejohn.org/projects/flexible-javascript-events/) from it's creator.

So end result (without jQuery), something like:

```
<style>
.clickedLine { background-color: red; }
.LetsMakeThatAClassOkay { color:#000; background:#fff; }
</style>
<pre class="LetsMakeThatAClassOkay">
<ol id="codeThatGetsClicked">
<li> line of code </li>
...
</ol>
</pre>
<script>
// Resig's addEvent linked above
function addEvent( obj, type, fn ) {
  if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
    obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
    obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );}
    obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
  } else
    obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
}
// What should happen to a line
function colorLine( event ) {
  var line = event.target;
  line.className = "clickedLine";
}
// Applying it
var code = document.getElementById("codeThatGetsClicked");
for(var i = 0; i < code.childNodes.length; i++){
  var child = code.childNodes[i];
  if (child.nodeType == 1 && child.tagName == "li") {
    addEvent(child, "click", colorLine);
  }
}
</script>
```

Now, with jQuery, it's almost one line of code. I'm sure you can read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) on that.